# 12VDC power adapter to power Arduino Uno and another device?

Tags: arduino, power, serial, adapter

I have a RHINO 12VDC power adapter (500mA). My goal is to use this power adapter to power an Arduino Uno and another device that is powered through a DB9 serial cable and takes an input voltage of 6 to 16VDC. I have a M/F Micro Connectors serial cable as well. My thought process is to...

1) Cut off the 2.1mm x 5.5mm jack 3-4 inches back

2) Strip both ends (exposing the ground and power on the adapter and now independent 2.1mm jack)

3) Cut the serial cable in half and strip it exposing all the wires on the Male end

4) Find the power and ground wires

5) Solder the power wires from the power adapter, serial cable, and 2.1mm jack together and wrap in electrical tape; do the same for the ground

Would this work safely for the devices?

Any advice would be appreciated. I just want to be able to power both devices with the one power adapter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your combined load is under 500 mA, there is no problem splicing the cables together.

You could skip that though, and tap the power from the arduino's raw input pin. For the uno R3 it's a diode voltage drop below the barrel connector voltage, but that's not an issue for you.